# Jcrop image preview with correct orientation changed using exif data

Tags: exif, jcrop

I have an image crop widget on a site. The image is cropped by the user with Jcrop before any upload takes place.

However, when the user uploads a photo which has orientation data (often from iPhone or similar), the photo appears wrongly orientated to them (compared to when they open in most basic photo viewers on their computer).

What I would like to do is to rotate the image to the orientation they are expecting. I am trying to extract the exif data from the image client side and then use this to add a css class to the preview image before initialising jcrop. The css class rotates the image appropriately.

At the moment, Jcrop seems to be creating its black box (for behind the image) and crop selection box as if the rotation never happened but the image rotation is happening so it looks all wrong.

Some code from the widget that I have attempted to modify is below. A jsfiddle including all the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qdkwb6w/1/). Note that setCoords sets another input that I haven't included as I didn't think it relevant.

Any help greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<input type="file" />
<div id="preview-image-holder">
    <img id="preview-image" />
</div>
```

javascript

```
var jcrop_api, ratio=1.3, real_width, real_height;

function setCoords(c) { //function to set value of cropping coords widget to a json string of the cropping coordinates
    $('input[id*=cropping_coords]').val(JSON.stringify(c));
}

function base64ToArrayBuffer (base64) {
    base64 = base64.replace(/^data\:([^\;]+)\;base64,/gmi, '');
    var binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}

function fixOrientation(image, orientationNum) {
    //adds css class to image dependent on orientation number
    switch(orientationNum) {
        case 2:
            image.addClass('flip'); break;
        case 3:
            image.addClass('rotate-180'); break;
        case 4:
            image.addClass('flip-and-rotate-180'); break;
        case 5:
            image.addClass('flip-and-rotate-270'); break;
        case 6:
            image.addClass('rotate-90'); break;
        case 7:
            image.addClass('flip-and-rotate-90'); break;
        case 8:
            image.addClass('rotate-270'); break;
    }
}

function initJcrop(selector) {
    //intialises jcrop on image
    $(selector).Jcrop({
        onSelect:setCoords,
        onChange:setCoords,
        bgColor:'black',
        bgOpacity:0.4,
        aspectRatio:ratio,
        trueSize:[real_width, real_height]
    }, function() {
        jcrop_api = this;
        dim = jcrop_api.getBounds();
        var x = 0, y = 0, x_ = dim[0], y_ = dim[1];
        var x_r = (x_ / ratio) - y_;
        var y_r = (y_ / ratio) - x_;

        if (x_r > 0) {
            x = x_r / 2;
        }
        if (y_r > 0) {
            y = y_r / 2;
        }
        jcrop_api.setSelect([x, y, dim[0], dim[1]]);
        jcrop_api.setOptions({
            allowSelect:false
        });
    });
}

function readImageURL(input) {
    //uses FileReader to change source of #preview-image to 
    //image from input
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            if(jcrop_api !== undefined) {
                jcrop_api.destroy();
                $('#preview-image').removeAttr('style');
            }
            var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(base64ToArrayBuffer(e.target.result));
            console.log(parseInt(exif.Orientation));
            var orientation = parseInt(exif.Orientation);
            fixOrientation($('#preview-image'), orientation);
            $('#preview-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('<img />').attr('src', e.target.result).load(function() {
                if ([5,6,7,8].indexOf(orientation)) {
                    real_width = this.height;
                    real_height = this.width;
                } else {
                    real_width = this.width;
                    real_height = this.height;
                }
                initJcrop($('#preview-image'));
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    }
}

$('input').change(function() {
    readImageURL(this);
});
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this in the end?

Comment: Also having this issue. The jcrop image element behind the preview pane is the orientation of the actual image, but the crop workspace is the rotated orientation. in the end the crop is true to what the user selected, but the preview pane is stretched because of the opposite orientation... still looking for a solution and seems like the same issue as what you are experiencing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034437/jcrop-incorrect-orientation-from-iphone-upload-how-i-can-do